# Xcode5, project deploys to device but get's a build error for simulator

Tags: xcode, xcode5, ios-simulator, build-error

When I deploy my app to my phone via xcode5 it works find, however when I try to deploy it to one of the simulators I get the following errors.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/benpearce/Downloads/MapKit.framework/MapKit, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/benpearce/Downloads/MapKit.framework/MapKit (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance", referenced from:
      -[MapKitView createViewWithOptions:] in MapKit.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKMapView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MapKit.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MKPinAnnotationView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MapKit.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The `MapKit` framework is missing a binary for the Simulator which is i386. The Simulator is a Mac application and needs a code resource compiled for the i386 Intel processor. Where did you get MapKit?

If this is Apple's MapKit you should just be including the framework provided with Xcode. It is added in Xcode by selecting the Project, Build Phases, Link Binaries with Libraries, +, select MapKit.framework.

Also the framework in in your Downloads directory, why?

Comment: It's a phone gap app, and the MapKit is a plugin.